# Ember Lighting Deploy Strategy - S3 NoSuchBucket error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Im deploying to S3 using ember-cli-deploy-lightning-pack. Ive followed various posts and screencasts setting this up.

on S3 i have a new bucket called emberdevlocal with nothing in it.

this is the snippet i have in my deploy.js file

```
  if (deployTarget === 'dev') {
ENV.build.environment = 'development';
ENV.redis.url = process.env.REDIS_URL || 'redis://0.0.0.0:6379/';
ENV.s3.bucket = 'emberdevlocal.s3.amazonaws.com';
```

}

I have my region set to

```
ENV.s3.region = 'us-west-2';
```

I have currently set the bucket permissions to wide open to make sure there is nothing going on there.

When i run the deploy it fails about half way through.

it sets the domain correctly

```
      Endpoint {
    protocol: 'https:',
    host: 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    port: 443,
    hostname: 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    pathname: '/',
    path: '/',
    href: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/',
    constructor: [Object] },
 region: 'us-west-2',
..........etc
```

its doing a PUT to

```
_header: 'PUT /emberdevlocal.s3.amazonaws.com/...........
```

I have the correct Keys being passed.

I just cant figure out why its timing out when trying to connect to the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I only put the bucket name for the `ember-cli-deploy-s3` plugin. Try simply

`ENV.s3.bucket = 'emberdevlocal';`

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have come across an issue where having dots in the bucket name can cause issues. I believe this was an AWS problem. Could you please try a bucket that doesn't include dots in the name (use dashes instead or something) and let me know if that fixes your problem?